# Distributions of components to distribution of vector

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have independent variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with tractable (not necessarily identical) distributions. I'm interested in the distribution of $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)'$ and, if possible, distributions of $\boldsymbol{c}'\boldsymbol{x}$ (linear combinations) and $\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{M}\boldsymbol{x}$ (quadratic forms) ($\boldsymbol{c}$ is a nonrandom vector and $\boldsymbol{M}$ a nonrandom positive semidefinite matrix).

Can you please recommend references that look at these issues? In particular, my $x_t$'s may not be normal; in fact, they can be discrete.

I have taken analysis and know some probability and measure theory.

Comment: uh... if the variables are independent then the distribution of the tuple is the product of the marginals. what's the problem here?